# Nifi IMAP consume Processor raising error

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting below error in IMAP Consume Processor.
2021-01-08 17:01:22,112 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-33] o.a.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP ConsumeIMAP[id=c31e4176-842d-3464-b870-2460ee675eee] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi…

2021-01-08 17:01:22,112 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-33] o.a.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP ConsumeIMAP[id=c31e4176-842d-3464-b870-2460ee675eee] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - IOException while copying message: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - IOException while copying message
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - IOException while copying message
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.fillMessageQueueIfNecessary(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:328)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.receiveMessage(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:381)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:195)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP.onTrigger(ConsumeIMAP.java:32)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while copying message
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.(MimeMessage.java:254)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage.(AbstractMailReceiver.java:557)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage.(AbstractMailReceiver.java:552)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.postProcessFilteredMessages(AbstractMailReceiver.java:415)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:342)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.fillMessageQueueIfNecessary(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:323)
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.FolderClosedIOException: null
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.forceCheckExpunged(IMAPInputStream.java:107)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.fill(IMAPInputStream.java:158)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:218)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream.read(IMAPInputStream.java:244)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.writeTo(IMAPMessage.java:849)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.(MimeMessage.java:245)
... 20 common frames omitted

Please help me to resolve the above error.